# Why sometimes title undefined on mobile version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

My html like this :

```
//for dekstop
<ul id="my-tab" class="hide-on-med-and-down">
    ...
    <li class="content accent-4">
      ...
    </li>
</ul>

//for mobile
<div id="my-tab-m" class="hide-on-large-only">
    <div class="row my-m-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript like this :

```
$('#my-tab>li').each(function () {
    var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    var imgScr = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

    var title
    if(href === 'spec')
        title = 'Spec'
    else if(href === 'app')
        title = 'App'
    else if(href === 'mc')
        title = 'Mc'


    $('<a href="#" data-href="' + href + '"><div class="col s" >'+title+'<div class="my-m-content"><img src="' + imgScr+'" /></div></div></a >').appendTo('#my-tab-m .my-m-container');

});
```

The script executed, it works. If I check with `inspect element` on the console and select mobile version, the title show

But if I access it directly by mobile phone, the title is sometimes legible, but the title is sometimes `undefined`

There exist 3 tabs. tab 1 and tab 2 undefined. tab 3 appears. sometimes all appears. this problem only occurs on mobile phones

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The only option is that `href` is neither of them. Try to add last `else` after all the `else if`s and alert the result, that will shows you what's the unknown `href`.

Comment: @Mosh Feu I had find a solution. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to change the title is: `document.title = "Your Title";`
This works on all devices and and I'm 99% sure it will work every time.

Comment: With `title` op mean the title on the link, not the page's title (:

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought you meant the page title.